# Bootstrap Glyphicons in Email

Tags: email, bootstrap

I am trying to prepare a custom email template.

I have a table and I am currently using an image to show as the "X" as below:

[image]

Since my first question was off topic, it put the question in my head as to whether an image of an "X" is the best method to explain to a user that something is not included - or should text be displayed simply stating "Yes" or "No"?

Thanks

Comment: We can't tell you how to do things. That's outside of the scope of the site. We can advise *what* do to from a UX point of view, but not *how* to do it.

Comment: I have updated the question - apologies for the off topic post.  It was my first post to the UX Experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite simple: you need to use YES/NO. You'll need to do a request external sources to load those icons, and many people blocks them, so by using icons, you'd be effectively blocking yourself and sending incomplete emails. That's why you need to use inline CSS styles in emails, because even loading your CSS stylesheet will be blocked.

The good news is that if you want, you can use [**HTML Entities**](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp). See the **[HTML entities character reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)** sheet to see how to use similar icons. They won't be exact or as good looking as glyphicons, of course, but you may achieve a nice layout with just some simple additional styling.

Just in case you're wondering, you can use ✓ and ✗ and do something as simple as

```
<span style="color:#f00; font-weight:bold">&cross;</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Icons are fine. What counts is arriving at the most intuitive (user friendly) solution to the problem. There are times that an icon works wonderfully well. There are other times that users are slowed down, confused by an excessive use of icons - especially icons that must be learned.

UX/IA geeks call adding an excessive amount of icons - especially non-intuitive ones - as adding "cognitive load."

I usually call them pimples that need to be removed from the mock-up/screen.